# jspm not loading bundles with --inject

Tags: systemjs, jspm

Been experimenting with jspm and systemjs over the weekend. Everything is working fine except for the bundling jspm offers. I can load individual files, but jsmp refuses to load the bundle file (which is optimized).

I'm creating the bundle file using:

```
jspm bundle lib/login assets/js/1-login.js --inject
```

This updates the config.js file which looks like:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: "/",
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    transpiler: "babel",
    babelOptions: {
        "optional": [
            "optimisation.modules.system"
        ]
    },
    paths: {
         "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
         "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
    },
    bundles: {
         "1-login.js": [
             "lib/login.js",
             "lib/sample.js"
         ]
    },
    map: {....}
});
```

lib/login.js

```
import * as sample from 'lib/sample'

export function test() {
    sample.testMethod();
}
```

lib/sample.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export function testMethod( ) {
    console.log( $('body') );
}
```

So, according to the jsmp docs:

> As soon as one of these modules is requested, the request is intercepted and the bundle is loaded dynamically first, before continuing with the module load.

It's my understanding that running

```
System.import('lib/login.js');
```

should load the bundle (and optimised file), but is doesn't - it just loads the actual file. What am I missing here? And as a bonus question, why is jquery not in the bundle list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, figured out where I went wrong.
I keep all the generated assets in `assets/js`, but in my config.json I didn't change the `baseUrl` to reflect this. I did in fact have the `baseUrl` set correctly in `package.json`, which is why jspm didn't throw a lot of errors.
This was the same reason jquery wasn't loading, so problem solved :)